# JDBC connection pool size under JBoos

Tags: jdbc, jboss

I want to restrict `JDBC connection` pool size in `JBoss`, but I don't want to modify internal server's config files. I use eclipse to deploy the web application, so is that possible to change that value from jboss-web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the connection pool size can be configures on a per-datasource basis, so you are not changing the internals of Jboss

basically you can set

```
<!-- The minimum connections in a pool/sub-pool. Pools are lazily constructed on first use -->
<min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
<!-- The maximum connections in a pool/sub-pool -->
<max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
```

on the *whatever*-ds.xml file in the `deploy` folder

Comment: I've just found [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html) tool that lets from application configuration source code set connections pool parameters. It's easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

No. Container-managed connection pools can't be modified from application code.